# Symbolic .and. and .or. expressions in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I know that in Fortran 90 the symbol for greater than (for example) has been changed from `.gt.` to `>`. Is this the case also for other logical expressions like `.and.` and `.or.`? Are there equivalent symbolic expressions for these as well?

Comment: Note that the token `.gt.` wasn't _changed_.  An additional form `>` was _introduced_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there are no such symbols nor have I noticed any interest or need from anyone who would call for such symbols before reading your question. So no, there are none in Fortran 90, none in Fortran 2018 and there are no plans for them for future Fortran AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

With I fort there is == and /= but many will point to 'non standard' as a rebuttal.

I use them routinely.

Comment: == and /= are standard.

Comment: aren't these all standard conforming?
( < or .lt. less than )
( <= or .le. less than or equal )
( == or .eq. equal )
( /= or .ne. not equal )
( > or .gt. greater than )
( >= or .ge. greater than or equal )

Comment: I suspect the previous comments are missing the point of this answer, so it may be better if you could clarify.  @SteveLionel, `==` and `/=` are not standard relational operators for logical operands and `.and.` and `.or.` are not standard operators for numeric operands.

Comment: I guess there is some confusion. Indeed, the numerical comparison operators all have "symbol" equivalents to the older .operator. forms, as of Fortran 90. There are also a set of operators for LOGICAL entities, for example: .AND., .OR., .NOT., .NEQV.. In standard Fortran you can't use the LOGICAL operators on numeric quantities nor the numerical operators on logical quantities. However, some compilers (especially the DEC heritage compilers such as Intel) allow you to mix these by default. See https://intel.ly/2GBVVzv for my post on this topic.